# Will it lead to Overfitting / Curse of Dimensionality

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, random-forest

Dataset contains :
15000 Observations/Rows
3000 Features/Columns

Can I train Machine Learning model on these Dataset

Comment: A lot of features does not always mean there will be overfitting. However, if there is multicolinearity in your data, that will definitely lead to overfitting. So it is not possible to tell just by looking at the dimensions of the data.

Comment: There are 15000 Unique Id'd and Each ID has a transaction Features.i-eID1 has 10 transaction .And Each Transaction has 30 Features.So I created a Single row which will contains 10*30 -> 300 Columns/Features.

Comment: Similarly ID2 has 100 Transaction and Each Transaction has 30 parameters.So I created a single of ID2 which contains 3000 features.

Comment: Maximum Transaction for Any ID found is 100 . Therefore 100*30 ->3000 features

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Plus, the comments is not the right place for adding such kind of info - please edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply the ML model but before that understanding of your problem statement come into a picture with all of the feature name available in the data set. If you are having big dataset try to convert it into a cluster of 2 or else take a small dataset to analyze what your data speaks about.
That is why population & sampling come to practical use.

You have to check whether accuracy of the train data set & test data set should be the same, if not then your model is memorizing instead of learning & here Regularization in Machine Learning comes into a picture.

Answer (score 0):

No one can answer this based on the information you provided. The simplest approach is to run a sanity check in the form of cross validation. Does your model perform well on unseen data? If it does, it is probably not overfit. If it does not, check if the model is performing well on the training data. A model that performs well on training data but not on unseen data is the definition of a model being overfit.